# convert an array of bytes into an integer

Tags: c, arrays, int, byte, ijvm

I'm working on IJVM project using C language.
First, I imported a binary file into my program, which should be parsed as words. 
Now I made a variable (text) which contains the binary and I need to convert it into an array of words. I got a hint

```
    int result = ((bytes[0] & 0xFF) << 24) |
    ((bytes[1] & 0xFF) <<16) |
    ((bytes[2] & 0xFF) << 8) | (bytes[3] & 0xFF);
```

This worked only for the first 4-bytes, What I need is an array of `result`.

I tried something like this, but it never worked .. :(

```
void type_converter(byte_t* text)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(text)/4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; i < sizeof(text)/4; i++) {

      int result[i] = ((text[j+0] & 0xFF) << 24) |
      ((text[j+1] & 0xFF) << 16) |
      ((text[j+2] & 0xFF) << 8) | (text[j+3] & 0xFF);
      instruction[i] = result;
      j =+ 4;
    }
  }
```

Comment: 'sizeof(text)' is sizeof(a pointer)

Comment: You have to pass array size as a separate parameter.

Comment: `for (int j = 0; i < sizeof(text)/4; i++) {` `i` or `j` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About OP's code sample:

- The inner loop doesn't make sense (or I didn't understand the intention).
- The outer loop, I would change to: `for (int i = 0; i + 3 < size; i += 4)`. Please, note the `i + 3`. It makes the loop safe against a partial amount of bytes at end of buffer. The `i += 4` makes the appropriate step in 4 byte jumps.
- The `size` is something you have to provide. As Martin already mentioned: `sizeof text` provides the size of the pointer. There is no chance to determine this by an operator (if you don't have direct access to original array). You should make a parameter `size` for this. (This is a very common solution in C programs.)
- Btw. there is no declaration for `result` or `instruction`. Hence, I would make one of them as another parameter of function.

So, your change function could look like this:

```
void type_converter(uint32_t *result, byte_t *text, size_t size)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i + 3 < size; i += 4) {
    result[i / 4]
      = ((text[i+0] & 0xFF) << 24)
      | ((text[i+1] & 0xFF) << 16)
      | ((text[i+2] & 0xFF) << 8)
      | (text[i+3] & 0xFF);
    }
  }
}
```

And, please, don't forget that `result` has to provide enough storage for `size / 4` `uint32_t` words.

---

As I just remembered how I did similar things in the past, this can be a little bit changed to prevent the `i + 3` in loop condition:

```
void type_converter(uint32_t *result, byte_t *text, size_t size)
{
  for (size_t i = 3; i < size; i += 4) {
    result[i / 4]
      = ((text[i-3] & 0xFF) << 24)
      | ((text[i-2] & 0xFF) << 16)
      | ((text[i-1] & 0xFF) << 8)
      | (text[i] & 0xFF);
    }
  }
}
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Nk9wX8gW677zdwR2)</kbd>

Note:

I just realized that this kind of byte combination is for big-endian numbers (highest byte in first position). For little-endian the indices had to be re-ordered.

Comment: @user8747585 You are welcome. - I've to admit that I did oversee some little bugs which I realized when I prepared an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Now, it is fixed.